# Using boolean to exit loops and then redo the loops

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java, so I don't know too many fancy stuff and I'm kind of stuck.

What I need to do is, take a text file; import the content into an `ArrayList`; check each line for a specific `Char` that is between two "#"; then check each line in the `ArrayList` again to see if one of the lines already has that `Char`; if it does, then I need to re-enter the whole `String` line and re-check it; and if it doesn't, then I need to put it at the bottom of the `ArrayList` and into the text file.

So far, I've gotten to the part where I need to check if the entered line's `Char` is repeating, but **I can only do it once**. If, for example, I enter it again I would get an **IndexOutOfBoundsException** because of one of the loops. So, I figured I'd use a `boolean` to exit the loops and re-enter them, but unfortunately, after entering the whole `String` once, it asks me to do it again in order to repeat the process because I'm exiting and entering the wrong loop, but I can't seem to figure out which.

```
ArrayList<String> Prices = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("file.txt"))){
        String CurrentLine;
        while ((CurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            Prices.add(CurrentLine);
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    boolean CheckSequence = true;
    boolean Redo = false;
    String StringArrayPrices[] = new String[Prices.size()];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    while (CheckSequence == true){
        System.out.println("Insert product in the following format, 'Product#Letter#Number': ");
        String ProductString = sc.nextLine();
        char ProductArray[] = ProductString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < Prices.size(); i++){
            StringArrayPrices[i] = Prices.get(i);
            char CharArrayPrice[] = StringArrayPrices[i].toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < CharArrayPrice.length && Redo == false; j++){
                if (CharArrayPrice[j] == '#' && CharArrayPrice[j+2] == '#'){
                    char TemporaryLetter = CharArrayPrice[j];
                    for (int k = 0; k < ProductArray.length && Redo == false; k++){
                        if (ProductArray[k] == '#' && ProductArray[k+2] == '#'){
                            char TemporaryLetter2 = ProductArray[k];
                            if (TemporaryLetter == TemporaryLetter2){
                                System.out.println("The letter is repeating. Enter product again or exit by writing '-1': ");
                                ProductString = sc.nextLine();
                                if (ProductString == "-1"){
                                    CheckSequence = false;
                                }
                                Redo = true;
                            }
                            if (TemporaryLetter != TemporaryLetter2){
                                Prices.add(ProductString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Right now, when I re-enter the `String`, I'm greeted with the first message "**"Insert product in the following format, 'Product#Letter#Number': "**", instead of the "**"The letter is repeating. Enter product again or exit by writing '-1': "**".

The first line should only show up when I'm entering a completely new `String` instead of when the previous one's repeating.

I hope I didn't make this too confusing.

Comment: 7 levels of indentation? Are you hoping to get a job on the linux kernel project?

Comment: Side note: `while (CheckSequence)` is preferred over `while (CheckSequence == true)`.

Comment: To add to @bradimus' side note: `CheckSequence` should be `checkSequence`

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't know any other way. I know there is one, I just don't know it.

Comment: @Michael Why is that?

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs?

Comment: @bradimus Well, you can input, for example, "Car#A#2". So, you need to check the "A", if it's repeating in the list or not.

Comment: @Michael I see. I'll make sure to do that from now on. I didn't know.

Comment: @Michael Why would you do that? That was very useful information. :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the loops is not the way to go.

I'm not entirely sure of the requirement, but I think this meets it.

Note that you should probably define a `Product` class to encapsulate much of this.

```
List<String> prices;
Set<String> letters;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
    prices = reader.lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
}

letters = prices.stream.map(p -> getLetter(p)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean shouldContinue = true;
while (shouldContinue) {
    System.out.println("Enter Product");
    String product = scanner.nextLine();
    if (product.equals("-1")) {
        shouldContinue = false;
    } else {
        String letter = getLetter(product);
        if (letters.contains(letter) {
            System.out.println("Repeat. Re-enter");
        } else {
            prices.add(product);
            letters.add(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

with the helper

```
private String getLetter(String s) {
    return s.split("#")[1]; //Or use the appropriate regex to extract the letter.
}
```

which could use some error handling.

To avoid java 8's streams,  You can use the same code you used in the question to build `prices` and

```
Set<String> letters = new HashSet<>();
for (String price : prices) {
    letters.add(getLetter(price));
}
```

Comment: Can it be done without the `stream.map` and `collectors` thing-ies? That's quite advanced for me. It's one of the reasons I'm using all of those loops.

Comment: Thank you so much, mate. Appreciate the help. I've very grateful. :3